# Generating a HATEOAS client library

Tags: rest, code-generation, restful-architecture, hateoas

Suppose I have a RESTful API for managing orders which uses [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) to facilitate HATEOAS:

```
GET /orders/2
  {
    "_links": {
      "self": "/orders/2",
      "items": "/orders/2/items"
    },
    "subtotal": 30.0,
    "shipped": false
  }
```

I want to write my client (application) using a set of interfaces so that, assuming that implementations of these interfaces are DI-d/built by DI-d factories, etc., I don't really (want to) have to care that they're backed by my RESTful API. As an example (pseudo C#/Java):

```
public interface Order {
  public void addItem(Item item);
  public float getSubtotal();
  public boolean getShipped();
}

Order order = ...;
Item item = ...;
order.addItem(item);
...(order.getSubtotal())...;
```

**My question is**: can I/does it make sense to generate implementations of the `Order`/`Item` interface from the API? By this I mean in a manner similar to that offered with C#/web services which export WSDLs.

I've been thinking about implementing `OPTIONS` for resources such as `/orders` and `/orders/{id}` so that I'd effectively have a HATEOAS API for traversing the schema of the API:

```
GET /orders/* (I'd need a suitable wildcard of course)
  {
    "_links": {
      "addItem": {
        "href": "/orders/{id}/items",
        "templated": true,
        "type": "method"
      }
    }
  }
```

Of course I could make this part of the `_links` object returned with any given resource (`/orders/2`, for instance) but that precludes static code generation.

I'm wondering if there's a sensible way to encapsulate the fact that if a particular link is provided, the related action should be available/performed, otherwise not.

*Note: In case it matters, I'm actually working in JavaScript (specifically with AngularJS). However, I'd still like to write my application using a set of conceptual interfaces/contracts.*

Comment: Since you're using JavaScript, are you aware / have you considered a foundation of something like hyperagent.js? http://weluse.github.io/hyperagent/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. Can you please send me some tutorial about why HAL is good to use?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: can I/does it make sense to generate implementations
>   of the Order/Item interface from the API? By this I mean in a manner
>   similar to that offered with C#/web services which export WSDLs.

It partially makes sense. By a simple CRUD API you can map the resources to the entities. By complex applications it does not work, because you map `URI`s to `resource`s and `METHOD URI` pairs to `operation`s. So every time if you need an operation not defined by HTTP, you have to create a new resource or at least a new URI for an already existing resource.

Some examples:

- transfer money from one account to another: `POST /transfer [acc1, acc2, amount, currency]` - the transfer does not necessary exist as an entity in your domain logic (don't try that kind of solution in production code unless you want bankruptcy :D)
- sending an email to another user: `POST /messages [recipient, message]`
- you can map resources to value objects too: `GET /users/123/address`
- you can use URIs to map reduce a collection: `GET /users?name="John"`
- you can use `PUT /users/123 [details]` instead of `POST /users [details]` to create a new user
- you can use `POST /player/123/xp/increment 10` instead of `PUT /player/123/xp [xp+10]` to update the experience points of a player

About the WSDL like solutions you can read alot more here: [Third Generation Web APIs - Markus Lanthaler](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/research/third-generation-web-apis-bridging-the-gap-between-rest-and-linked-data.pdf).

My personal opinion that it does not worth the effort to build such a system, because it has more drawbacks than advantages.